# Slicing with selected indices (translating Matlab to Python)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy-slicing

Please, what is the best way to write this Matlab code in Python? 'x' being a matrix and 'value' is a selection parameter.

Matlab: `y = x ( find ( x(:,1) == value ) , : )`

I am writing this...

Python: `y = x [ np.squeeze ( np.nonzero ( x[:,0] == value ) ) , : ]`

could it be simpler?

Thanks

Comment: If `x` is a numpy array: `x[x[:,0]==value,:]` ? Also for the matlab code, `find` convert your binary index to linear index, it's useless here: you can simply write `x(x(:,1)==value)`

Comment: Thanks! It seems quite obvious now. By the way, double thanks, for I always used the 'find' in Matlab for this purpose too.